# Is there any way to predict next random number?

Tags: string, function, actionscript-3, flash

I want to make roulette wheel in ActionScript3.

I have full source of other roulette, but it generates next number after spin(Eventclick), so I know next number as I click spin button(The value changes faster than visual, before ball stops rotating I know where it falls).

In my roulette I want to know what will be next number, before player click spin button. Sorry if I can't explain what I want exactly, but hope you will understand.

```
package de.polygonal.core.math.random {

    public class Random extends Object
    {

        public function Random() : void
        {
            return;
        }// end function

        public static function rand() : int
        {
            return Math.random() * 2147483647;
        }// end function

        public static function randRange(param1:int, param2:int) : int
        {
            var _loc_3:* = param1 - 0.4999;
            var _loc_4:* = param2 + 0.4999;
            return _loc_3 + (_loc_4 - _loc_3) * Math.random() + 16384.5 - 16384;
        }// end function

        public static function randSym(param1:int) : Number
        {
            var _loc_2:* = -param1 - 0.4999;
            var _loc_3:* = param1 + 0.4999;
            return _loc_2 + (_loc_3 - _loc_2) * Math.random() + 16384.5 - 16384;
        }// end function

        public static function randBool() : Boolean
        {
            return Math.random() < 0.5;
        }// end function

        public static function frand() : Number
        {
            return Math.random();
        }// end function

        public static function frandRange(param1:Number, param2:Number) : Number
        {
            return param1 + (param2 - param1) * Math.random();
        }// end function

        public static function frandSym(param1:Number) : Number
        {
            var _loc_2:* = -param1;
            return _loc_2 + (param1 - _loc_2) * Math.random();
        }// end function

    }
}
```

Comment: Generate a random number when the app loads and store it somewhere... var theRandomNumber = rand(); Then when they click spin use "theRandomNumber", spin the wheel, then generate the next random. That way you always know the next random number and clicking uses the random, then generates the next. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So `var _loc_3:* = param1`, is it? Not even ashamed to use the decompiled variables names from a Haxe output SWF. I think you got downvoted for decompiled "code dump" without own effort to fix issue that we can advise about. Just so you know for future Questions (always **show what you've tried** to avoid downvotes/bans).

Comment: @VC.One, I've written that I had had full source of other roulette! I'm beginner in programming and there is no shame in asking for help. I edit codes only for my own interests and don't get any benefits from other's work.

Comment: @Unnamed it's no problem. It's your first day. Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm just saying it looks bad when you do a "code dump" with no part where you try something (ie: own prediction code or some theory for us to help you implement). _"I'm beginner in programming and there is no shame in asking for help"_ agreed. Keep it up. **PS:** Also make sure you mark good/correct solutions by clicking the `✔` icon next to Answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's as comment suggests. All you need is a queue of random numbers generated ahead.

```
package
{
    public class Predictable
    {
        static public const FORESIGHT:int = 10;

        static public var nextRandoms:Array = preFill();

        static public function preFill():Array
        {
            if (!nextRandoms) nextRandoms = new Array;

            while (nextRandoms.length < FORESIGHT)
                nextRandoms.push(Math.random());

            return nextRandoms;
        }

        static public function random():Number
        {
            preFill();

            return nextRandoms.shift();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Learn the next random number.
var a:Number = Predictable.nextRandoms[0];

// Generate next random number.
var b:Number = Predictable.random();
```